# Función lambda no captura atributos de la clase en C++

Tags: c++, lambda

Resulta que tengo una clase `Ratings` que es iterable solamente a través de su método foreach y recibe un lambda como único parámetro. El problema viene cuando intento usarla pasándole el atributo map_ en el método print de la clase `Score`.

```
class Ratings{
    std::vector<std::string> vector_;
public:
    Ratings(std::initializer_list<std::string> list)
        : vector_{list}
    {}

    template<typename CALLBACK>
    void foreach(CALLBACK callback) const{
        for(auto &item : vector_){
            callback(item);
        }
    }
};

class Score{
    std::map<std::string,int> map_;
public:
    Score()
        : map_{
            {"mal"         ,0},
            {"insuficiente",1},
            {"aceptable"   ,2},
            {"bien"        ,3}
        }
    {}
    void print(const Ratings &ratings){
        // error al intentar capturar map_ en el lambda
        ratings.foreach([&map_](const auto &str){
            auto it = map_.find(str);

            if(it != map_.end()){
                std::cout<<it->first<<" ["<<it->second<<"]\n";
            }
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: Exactamente, ¿ **Qué error** estás obteniendo ? Un comentario `error al intentar capturar map_ en el lambda` no es muy descriptivo que digamos. ¿ De compilación ? ¿ De ejecución ? Y ya puestos a formular correctamente la pregunta, ¿ Qué versión de C++ estás usando ? Te recomiendo que visites [El Centro de Ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help), concretamente [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Un saludo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cuando usas lambdas sobre una función de instancia no capturas sus atributos, sino `this`. Así que en lugar de `[&map_]` debes usar `[&]`.

Para más información, consulta [la documentación](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda#Lambda_capture).